# Add iframe to Appcelerator application

Tags: android, ios, iframe, appcelerator, youtube-iframe-api

I need to use iframe  to show the first frame of a vide in an application that im developing.

I have my webView like this:

```
var myWebView =  Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height : deviceHeight * 0.04,
    width : deviceHeight * 0.04,
    left : deviceWidth * 0.03,
    backgroundColor : "red",
    url : "/local.html",
});
```

and this is my local.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https:(myLink) frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the frame loads but don't occupies my entire WebView.

Or is there a better way to load an iframe to a WebView in appcelerator with JavaScript?

I don't know how tho due this.

Dose some one have any suggestion tho due this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need the iframe around it? Setting the URL to your link would also work.

One way would be to set the meta viewport: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and if the iframe should be fullscreen (not 100px) it would be something like:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```